# Android Studio Monitor not showing all logs but Android Device manager does

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

When I run Android Studio and use the Android monitor tab, I only see partial logs.  Double checked filters, device and log level.

I only see the full set of logs, as expected, when I use the Tools > Android > Android Device Manager.

How can I fix the Android Studio monitor to show full set of logs?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are not seeing in the monitor tab?

Comment: I expect to see this debug level message: 11-11 08:06:55.419: D/WSClientManager(21250):  Sending request

Answer (score 4):

Restarting Logcat can help you to solve this problem

[image]